# find y' if y=ln(7x^2+3y^2)

Tags: calculus

okay so i've asked this question before and i really appreciate the help you guys gave me. i want to see if what i've done so far is correct.

1st step: (7x^2+3y^2)'/ 7x^2+3y^2

2nd step: 14x+6yy'/ 7x^2+3y^2

3rd step: 14x/7x^2+3y^2 + 6yy'/7x^2+3y^2

4th step: y'- 6yy'/7x^2+3y^2= 14x/7x^2+3y^2

5th step: y'(1-6y/7x^2+3y^2)= 14x/7x^2+3y^2

6th step: y'((7x^2+3y^2)-6y)=14x

final step? y'= 14x/7x^2+3y^2-6y 
this is what i ended up with as my answer

also forgive me for my formatting.

Comment: You mean the partial of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $y$?

Comment: hmm, im not sure what you mean. the problem given to is written in the same form as the title i gave it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good! here is another way that slightly simplifies the arithmetic

$$ y = \ln(7x^2+3y^2)  \implies      e^y =  7x^2+3y^2  $$

Differentiating implicitly and isolating $y'$ gives you the same answer

Comment: Thank heavens! this means i actually got it right correct? if so i am really happy i got this!

Comment: Yes! good job :)

Comment: Sweet! thanks a ton for the help ganeshie8

Answer (score 1):

This is solution:
[image]

if you will need more explain say.